# Nextflow Process `MULTIMETRICS` declares 3 input channels but 5 were specified

Tags: nextflow

I am creating a nextflow pipeline for analysing genomics data. The pipeline can carry out all steps up to creating BAM files and marking duplicates. However I am unable to carry the created BAM files over from my MARK_DUPLICATES step into the GATK MultiMetrics tool as the MULTMETRICS process declares 3 input channels but 5 were specified.

```
Process `MULTIMETRICS` declares 3 input channels but 5 were specified
```

The MARKDUPLICATES process

```
process MARK_DUPLICATES {

    cpus 10

    publishDir params.outdir, mode:'move'



    container 'broadinstitute/gatk:latest' 

    input:

    tuple val(sample_id), path(reads)

    output:

    path "${sample_id}_MarkedDup.bam"

    path "${sample_id}_MarkedDuplicates.txt"

    path "${sample_id}_MarkedDup.bai"

    script:

    """

    gatk MarkDuplicates I=${reads[0]} O=${sample_id}_MarkedDup.bam M=${sample_id}_MarkedDuplicates.txt CREATE_INDEX=true 



    """   


}
```

The MULTIMETRICS process:

```
process MULTIMETRICS {


    container 'broadinstitute/gatk:latest'

    input:
    path "${sample_id}_MarkedDup.bam"
        path(genome)
    val genomeid


    output:

    tuple val(sample_id), path("${sample_id}_multimetrics")

    script:
    """

    gatk CollectMultipleMetrics I=${reads} O=${sample_id}_multimetrics R=${genome}/$genomeid

    """
}
```

The workflow:

```
    picard_ch=MARK_DUPLICATES(addreadgroups_ch)

//    picard_ch.view()

    multimetrics_ch=MULTIMETRICS(picard_ch, params.genomefile, params.genomeid)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what's happening.

`MARK_DUPLICATES` declares 3 separate files in the output declaration. Since you've not specified which you want to send to `MULTIMETRICS` the `picard_ch` channel will have all 3 files. Though I do find it a little strange it's not trying to process each individually.

This can be solved with more explicit output declarations. Here is one solution channeling all `MARK_DUPLICATES` outputs into a single channel:

```
process MARK_DUPLICATES {
    cpus 10
    publishDir params.outdir, mode:'copy' // The docs suggest unless this is the final process, you shouldn't you use 'move'
    container 'broadinstitute/gatk:latest' 

    input:
    tuple val(sample_id), path(reads)

    output:
    tuple val(sample_id), path("${sample_id}_MarkedDup.bam"), path("${sample_id}_MarkedDup.bai"), path("${sample_id}_MarkedDuplicates.txt"), emit: picard_ch

    script:
    """
    gatk MarkDuplicates I=${reads[0]} O=${sample_id}_MarkedDup.bam M=${sample_id}_MarkedDuplicates.txt CREATE_INDEX=true 
    """
}
process MULTIMETRICS {
    container 'broadinstitute/gatk:latest'

    input:
    tuple val(sample_id), path(bam), path(bai), path(txt)
    path(genome)
    val genomeid


    output:
    tuple val(sample_id), path("${sample_id}_multimetrics"), emit: mm_ch

    script:
    """
    gatk CollectMultipleMetrics I=${reads} O=${sample_id}_multimetrics R=${genome}/$genomeid
    """
}

workflow {
    ...
    MARK_DUPLICATES(addreadgroups_ch)
    MULTIMETRICS(MARK_DUPLICATES.out.picard_ch, params.genomefile, params.genomeid)
}
```

Alternatively, you could just emit the bam from `MARK_DUPLICATES` like this:

```
process MARK_DUPLICATES {
    ...

    output:
    tuple val(sample_id), path("${sample_id}_MarkedDup.bam"), emit: picard_bam
    path("${sample_id}_MarkedDup.bai"), emit: picard_bai
    path("${sample_id}_MarkedDuplicates.txt"), emit: picard_txt
    ...
}
```

The `MULTIMETRICS` input declaration would need to change to:

```
process MULTIMETRICS {
    ...
    input:
    tuple val(sample_id), path(bam)
    ...
}
```

And the workflow:

```
workflow {
    ...
    MARK_DUPLICATES(addreadgroups_ch)
    MULTIMETRICS(MARK_DUPLICATES.out.picard_bam, params.genomefile, params.genomeid)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried both suggested fixes and the first one worked great. However the second did throw up the following error message: ERROR ~ No such variable: Exception evaluating property 'out' for nextflow.script.ChannelOut, Reason: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: out for class: groovyx.gpars.dataflow.DataflowBroadcast

Comment: Huh, that's confusing. My guess is there is a problem with the output channels from `MARK_DUPLICATES`. Are you sure the `emit: picard_bam` is the same channel name used for `MARK_DUPLICATES.out.picard_bam`? Otherwise I'm stumped without seeing the scripts and logs.

Regardless, I think the first example makes more sense anyway. Emitting the bam and bai together is an obvious pairing than each file individually.